# Matching two EditText entries doesn't work with asterisks (fieldOne.matches(fieldTwo))

Tags: java, android, passwords

I'm working on a Register Activity with the user e-mail and password getting stored in a Firebase database. Everything works just perfect except for one thing: as you can see the code does allow special characters to be used in the password (even though you only need to have at least 8 characters including at least both a letter and a number), still I get the "passwords don't match" Toast error message if I try to use a password like "abcd1234*" as I coded here:

```
 }
    else if (!(password.matches(repassword))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

If I try with the same exact password without including the asterisk it works just fine. It's like the code gets confused when it comes to match two special characters. Here is the full code:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button CreateAccountButton;
private EditText InputEmail, InputPassword, ReInputPassword;
private TextView terminiRead;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    CreateAccountButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_btn);
    InputEmail = findViewById(R.id.signup_email_input);
    InputPassword = findViewById(R.id.signup_psw_input);
    ReInputPassword = findViewById(R.id.signup_repsw_input);
    terminiRead = findViewById(R.id.termini);

    terminiRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,TerminiDiServizio.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreateAccount();
        }
    });
}


private void CreateAccount() {


    String email = InputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();
    String repassword = ReInputPassword.getText().toString();

    Pattern PSWPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$");

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert an e-mail address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (!(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())){
       Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid e-mail address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert a password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(repassword)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reinsert your password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (!(password.matches(PSWPattern.pattern()))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "The password length must be at least 8 and containing at least a number and a letter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (!(password.matches(repassword))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        ValidateAccount(email,password,repassword);
    }
}

private void ValidateAccount(final String email, final String password, final String repassword) {
    final DatabaseReference RootRef;
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("User").child(email.replace(".",",")).exists()))
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                userdataMap.put("email", email.replace(".",","));
                userdataMap.put("password", password);
                userdataMap.put("repassword", repassword);

                RootRef.child("User").child(email.replace(".",",")).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Thanks for signing up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "An error occurred, retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "E-mail address is already in use", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`password.matches(repassword)` expect Regex to be passed and you pass it a string

- `password.equalsIgnoreCase(repassword)` for case insensitive
- `password.equals(repassword)` for case sensitive

Comment: Your hint led me to read more about equals() and equalsIgnoreCase() methods, I thank you for that. I couldn't use equalsIgnoreCase() because obviously I want my password to be case-sensitive, but I did use equals() with a "!" :)

Comment: Aah, I forget you need to make it case sensitive so you are right

Answer (score 1):

Solution found: just use the equals() method instead of matches() method:

```
(!(password.equals(repassword)));
```

Don't forget the ! (logical opposite) at the beginning if you're trying to make something happen if the two entries DON'T match. :)